# get_user(id) cant find user - returns None (self bot discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to DM myself using a self bot. I am trying to use the `get_user()` function in my code.

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='', self_bot=True)

counter = 0
userID = 695724603406024726

@bot.event
async def dm(userID):
    print('Running Function')
    global counter

    if counter <= 0:
        print('Finding user.')
        counter += 1

        user = bot.get_user(userID)

        print('user:',user)

        await user.send("Hello")
        print('message sent')

    return


bot.loop.create_task(dm(userID))
bot.run(token, bot=False)
```

Instead, I am returned with this error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-90e5e962a6e9>", line 24, in dm
    await user.send("Hello")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

The bot can't find the user and returns a `None` value. I have tested multiple ID's and am unsure what the problem is.

Comment: It's telling you your `user` object doesn't have a `send` method.  Have you confirmed this method exist in whatever package you're deriving this from?

Comment: @Chris the user object must be a discord object. I am trying to obtain it from the get_user function. It isn't telling me that it doesn't have a send method, it is telling me that the user cannot be found thus popping up with the NoneType error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could always use the coroutine `client.fetch_user(id)` to get it done. `get_user()` takes it from cache so when fresh, doesn't work most of the times.

In your case:

````py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='', self_bot=True)

counter = 0
userID = 695724603406024726

async def dm(userID):
    print('Running Function')
    global counter

    if counter <= 0:
        print('Finding user.')
        counter += 1

        user = await bot.fetch_user(userID)

        print('user:',user)

        await user.send("Hello")
        print('message sent')

    return


bot.loop.create_task(dm(userID))
bot.run(token, bot=False)```
````

Comment: Yes this solved my problem! I'm still not sure what my issue was (considering the OP's solution of waiting did not work for me) but this fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You're attaching your task to the event loop and running it immediately, which means it tries to run before your bot is connected and ready.

One of the things your bot does when it first connects is build an internal cache of objects it knows about, which is what `get_user` draws from (this is why it's a regular function and not a coroutine)

So you just need to add a wait to the task so that it waits until the bot is ready:

```
async def dm(userID):
    print('Running Function')
    global counter
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    ...
```

Notice I removed the `bot.event` too.  There is no `dm` event, so that decorator wasn't doing anything.

Comment: So this seemed to solve the solution, but it takes a long time to 'get ready'. Is there any solution to make it faster?

Comment: It depends how many guilds your bot is connected to and what size they are.  There are some configurations for [`Client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client) you can experiment with, and if you have more than 1000 guild you may want to switch to an `AutoShardedClient`