# Im getting a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name' in my leaderboard command that I built

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I built a leaderboard command for my bot to show the richest people on my server and I'm getting a    ret
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name' error. Below is my code. Anyone know any fix?

````py
@bot.command(aliases = ["lb"])
async def leaderboard(ctx,x = 1):
    users = await get_bank_data()
    leader_board = {}
    total = []
    for user in users:
        name = int(user)
        total_amount = users[user]["wallet"] + users[user]["Test Subject Zone"]
        leader_board[total_amount] = name
        total.append(total_amount)

    total = sorted(total,reverse=True)    

    em = discord.Embed(title = f"Top {x} Richest People" , description = "This is decided on the basis of raw money in the bank and wallet",color = discord.Color(0xfa43ee))
    index = 1
    for amt in total:
        id_ = leader_board[amt]
        member = bot.get_user(id_)
        name = member.name
        em.add_field(name = f"{index}. {name}" , value = f"{amt}",  inline = False)
        if index == x:
            break
        else:
            index += 1

    await ctx.send(embed = em)```
````

Comment: How have you tried debugging this so far? Did you step through this line-by-line in a debugger to make sure that `users` contains what you expect, as well as if `name = int(user)` is working as expected?

Comment: Where is `member` defined?

Comment: @RandomDavis Yes I have because if I remove that line everything works perfectly except it only shows  the ID of the user and the name command is supposed to show the name instead of the userID

Comment: @tralph3 member = bot.get_user(id_) line 16

Comment: @jguardia So have you verified that the line `id_ = leader_board[amt]` is returning an `id`? Have you verified that `bot.get_user(id_)` returns a user, as opposed to `None`? Have you verified that `users[user]["wallet"]` and `users[user]["Test Subject Zone"]` are returning the correct thing? Does `users = await get_bank_data()` return the correct data?

Comment: @RandomDavis now that I check again I see `bot.get_user(id_)` returns none any way to  fix this?

Comment: I have no idea but I googled that issue and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61112322/get-userid-cant-find-user-returns-none-self-bot-discord-py), does that help?