# How do I DM a user with just their id

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to be able to pass in a users id and the bot will send them a dm

```
@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, userid, message):
   user = bot.get_user(int(userid))
   await user.send(message)
```

The API says it return a null object if it can't find the user which it did return a `null` object. This is weird because I know I put in my discord id so I have no idea why it's returning a `Null` object.

Comment: You put in the user ID right? Not the discriminator?

Comment: `get_user` doesn't make API calls. It accesses the cache. You may be getting None because the user isn't in the cache yet.

Comment: Sorry what is the Chache?

Comment: Cache is the local storage. It's used on the web app or app of discord for user clients as well. It helps in reducing API calls

Comment: So how do you get in the chache?

Comment: The cache is accessed with `get_` prefixed functions. See the documentation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61112322/get-userid-cant-find-user-returns-none-self-bot-discord-py this is solution thanks everyone for helping

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get\_user(id) cant find user - returns None (self bot discord.py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61112322/get-userid-cant-find-user-returns-none-self-bot-discord-py)