# How to send a DM to a user using just their user id

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I would like to send a dm to a user just by using their user id that I copied from their profile.

This is the code that I made, but it didn't work.

```
@client.command()
async def dm(userID, *, message):
    user = client.get_user(userID)
    await user.send(message)
```

This is the error that appeared:

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Comment: Does the code output any errors?

Comment: @Mous yes I edited the post already

Comment: Then it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61112322/get-userid-cant-find-user-returns-none-self-bot-discord-py. Use `client.fetch_user` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the user id to user object then create dm and sent the message as following:

```
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx,user:discord.User, *, message = None):
    if message is None:
        await ctx.send("Enter the message to be sent")
    try:
        channel = await user.create_dm()
        await channel.send(message)
    except discord.Forbidden:
        await ctx.send("could not send the message")
```

And you must use try block cause there are some users that are not allowing dm like me :)

[as the docs say](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=user#discord.DMChannel.send) It raises Forbidden when the bot don't have the perms

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change the userID argument to `user: discord.User`. That argument will accept user mentions (@user), usernames (user), and ids (904360748455698502). The full code would now be:

```py
@client.command()
async def dm(user: discord.User, *, message):
    channel = await user.create_dm()
    await channel.send(message)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because a DM channel has not been created with the user.

Comment: @J Muzhen Thanks for pointing that out! I have updated my code to create a dm channel.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is partially correct. However, from the discord.py API reference, a `User` object is not messageable, i.e. you cannot use the `send()` function directly on the `User` itself.

To solve this problem, we need to first create a `DMChannel` with the user, and then send a message into the `DMChannel`.

Here is the working code:

```py
@client.command()
async def dm(userID: int, *, message):
    user = client.get_user(userID)
    dmChannel = user.create_dm()
    await dmchannel.send(message)
```

Comment: resulted in this error: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_dm'

Comment: @MiroPletscher It means that `user` is `None`. This indicates that the user with the given ID was not found. This is because `userID` is by default a `str` object. I have updated my answer to fix this bug.

Comment: Does the new updated code work for you?

Comment: I changed the code and it still resulted in the same error

Comment: @MiroPletscher Then this means that the client could not find the user with the given ID. The user has to share at least one server with the bot for `get_user()` to get the user properly.

Comment: Yes I realized that thanks for your help