# Discord.py getting avatar if user isn't in same guild

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, nextcord

How can I get a user avatar if the user is not in the same guild as the bot, but in mutual guilds?

I'm trying to get the user avatar from a mutual server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to get the user

You can use `await bot.fetch_user(user_id)` to retrieve any user. You don't want to use `bot.get_user(user_id)` for various reasons [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61112322/get-userid-cant-find-user-returns-none-self-bot-discord-py).

### How to get the image url

You can use the avatar URL by using `user.avatar.url` (user being the class fetched by `bot.fetch_user()` and `avatar` is an asset *links below*)

### Example code

```
@tree.command()
async def avatar_from_another_guild(ctx, id_:str):  # id_ is the user id to fetch
    print(id_)
    user = await bot.fetch_user(int(id_))  # retrieve user here
    try:
        await ctx.response.send_message(user.avatar)  # send final product
    except AttributeError as err:  # error catching if invalid id is inserted
        print(user)
        await ctx.response.send_message("User not found." + str(err))
```

### Example code product

[image: image of example code working as intended]

### py-cord variation

```
@bot.slash_command()  # this is the only difference, everything else is the same
async def avatar_from_another_guild(ctx, id_):
    print(id_)
    user = await bot.fetch_user(int(id_))
    try:
        await ctx.respond(user.avatar)
    except AttributeError:
        print(user)
        await ctx.respond("User not found.")
```

*Note: product is the same for both*

### Resources

- [getting the user](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=fetch_user#discord.Client.fetch_user)
- [getting user image as asset](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=user%20avatar#discord.User.avatar)
- [asset URL](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=user%20avatar#discord.Asset.url)